# R data.table memory address issue

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R. Let's call it `x`. I plug this into a list as follows:

`pars <- list(x = x)`

Since I've not made a copy I expect the memory addresses given by `sapply(list(x, pars$x), tracemem)` to be the same. They are (!).

The (potential) issue arises when I save `x` and `pars$x` into a `save_much.RData` file and then reload `load(file = "save_much.RData")`. Upon reload when I get the memory addresses given by `sapply(list(x, pars$x), tracemem)` I get different memory addresses. Therefore a deep copy has been made when I didn't explicitly want that to happen.

In summary try the following and you will see the issue:

```
x <- data.table(rnorm(100, 0, 1))
pars <- list(x = x)
sapply(list(x, pars$x), tracemem)
save("x", "pars", file = "save_much.RData")
rm("x", "pars")
gc()
load(file = "save_much.RData")
sapply(list(x, pars$x), tracemem)
```

This becomes a problem for me as I have written a reference class where `x` and `pars` are attributes. My expectation is that since `x` and `pars$x` point to the same object I shouldn't get different memory addresses upon reloading the particular instance of this reference class.

Has anybody faced this issue before with data.table? My apologies if this has already been posted as a question: first time on SO!

This is what I see when I run the code on R-3.2.2 and data.table version 1.9.6:

```
library(data.table)
data.table 1.9.6  For help type ?data.table or https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki
The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
x <- data.table(rnorm(100, 0, 1))
pars <- list(x = x)
sapply(list(x, pars$x), tracemem)
[1] "<0000000005EFB9B8>" "<0000000005EFB9B8>"
save("x", "pars", file = "save_much.RData")
rm("x", "pars")
gc()
used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 268518 14.4     460000 24.6   350000 18.7
Vcells 480006  3.7    1023718  7.9   786276  6.0
load(file = "save_much.RData")
sapply(list(x, pars$x), tracemem)
[1] "<0000000005F06618>" "<0000000005F06A68>"
```

Comment: It's impossible to get the same address if you save (to file) and then load. It's a really strange requirement anyway... why do you check memory addresses after saving/reloading ?

Comment: My point is that I make a shallow copy of x with pars$x. Not a deep one. I get a deep copy upon reloading when I never explicitly requested it. 2 handles pointing to the same object. Upon reload I have 2 handles to different objects: a deep copy has been made.

Comment: x and pars$x should point to the same address. That breaks upon reload.

Comment: Incredibly (I didn't know of this data.table feature) on my machine seems to behave like you want, i.e. the first sapply returns something like `<addr123> <addr123>`, and the second one returns `<addr456> <addr456>` (so both address are coincident). I'm using data.table version 1.9.6

Comment: Cool! I think my data.table version may be older (need to check - on the underground!). It may have been an issue that has been fixed. Thanks for checking. You are getting the expected results!

Comment: I'm also getting the same address, using data.table 1.9.6

Comment: I had data.table version 1.9.4. I installed 1.9.6 however still getting the same issue. Maybe this is a R version issue.

Comment: Or could be a Windows / Linux issue. I'll check and get back.

Comment: I'm still getting that same issue with R-3.2.2 and data.table version 1.9.6. I'm running this on Windows.